# Marionette CompositeView -> LayoutView -> ItemView - ViewEvents

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

i've got a CompositeView using a Layout with several Regions as ItemView:

```
  var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        itemView: Layout,
        template: _.template(...)
  });

  var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template:  _.template(...),
    regions: {
      mainRegion: ".main",
      listRegion: ".list"    
    },
    onRender : function () {
      this.mainRegion.show(new SingleView({model : this.model}));
    }    
  });

  var SingleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:  _.template(...),
    initialize: function(){
       // Forward view events - is there a better way?
        this.on('Module:submodule:action1', function(ev){
        app.vent.trigger("Module:submodule:action1", ev);
      });
    },
    triggers: {
      "click .ui_toggleComplete": "Module:submodule:action1",
    }
  });
```

This makes it possible to receive the SingleView Event via app.on('Module:submodule:action1',...);

I would like to use the model events directly without forwarding them to the event aggregator (app.vent).

Before i implemented the Layout as itemView i could do something like CompositeView.on('itemview:Module:submodule:action1',...); that's how i would like to handle the ItemViews events again. (I need the Layout to display further collections etc...)

Comment: Why so complicated? I merged the Layout with the SingleView and the itemview:Module:submodule:action1 events came throu